# Can anyone explain the output of FC?

Tags: excel, csv, compare, filecompare

I am comparing two CSV files but have a hard time understanding what it's trying to tell me.

Comparing files Dollar.csv and NODOLLAR.CSV
***** Dollar.csv
:
5
9

***** NODOLLAR.CSV
:
3
3

---

This is the output, can anyone explain what it means?

Comment: What application are you using for the comparison?

Comment: I used the fc in Windows. fc Dollar.Csv NoDollar.csv > compare.txt was my input

Comment: Ah, I'm stupid. The only difference is the time it was created, where the first file was created at 1:59:33 and the other file at 1:59:59